# How to do server side data fetching only once for pages sharing a persistent layout in Next.js?

Tags: next.js, seo, server-side-rendering

I have a persistent layout that needs data to be fetched on the server side. Since you can only call `getServerSideProps` from a page, my solution is to fetch the data from the page and then pass it to my layout. The issue is that the layout should persist across pages, and this requires me to refetch the data on each page change.

Folder structure:

```
├── /collection

│   ├──[contractaddress]

│   │  ├── dashboard.tsx
│   │  ├── items.tsx
│   │  ├── analytics.tsx
```

Example of a URL: "/collection/0xed5af388653567af2f388e6224dc7c4b3241c544/dashboard"

Dashboard, analytics, and items are all different views of a collection, and share a `CollectionLayout`.

I've been able to follow [Adam Wathan's guide on persistent layouts](https://adamwathan.me/2019/10/17/persistent-layout-patterns-in-nextjs/), which has worked great. Components in `CollectionLayout` which are shared across the views persist state across the different views.

I'm using `getServerSideProps` to fetch data about the collection and then I pass it back to `CollectionLayout` like so:

```
Dashboard.getLayout = function getLayout(page: ReactElement) {
  return (
    <CollectionLayout collection={page.props.collection}>
      {page}
    </CollectionLayout>
  );
};
```

I'm running into a few problems:

- Layouts do not allow for sever side data fetching. Although I could fetch the data that the layout needs on the client side, I would prefer to do it on the server side so that I can use that data for SEO purposes.
- Since I am fetching the layout data within each view (page), I am adding unnecessary strain on the server by making multiple calls for redundant data.

My ideal state is to make 1 request per [contractaddress]. That data is then passed to `CollectionLayout` which persists across views.

I did see that there are updates coming to layouts (https://nextjs.org/blog/layouts-rfc). The ability to call getServerSideProps in a layout file would solve all of my problems.

In the meantime, is there any way for me to get around this in Next 12.2.2?

dashboard.tsx

```
import { GetServerSideProps } from "next";
import { NextSeo } from "next-seo";
import type { ReactElement } from "react";
import { CollectionLayout } from "../../../../layouts/CollectionLayout";
import type { NextPageWithLayout } from "../../../_app";

type Props = {
  collection: {
    contractAddress: string;
    name: string;
    description: string;
    image: string;
  };
};

const Dashboard: NextPageWithLayout<Props> = ({ collection }) => {
  return (
    <div className="w-full">
      <NextSeo title={collection.name} description={collection.description} />
      <div className="bg-purple-400 h-[400px] w-[500px]">Dashboard</div>
    </div>
  );
};

// This gets called on every request
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async () => {
  // This data should only be fetched once and then persisted across views
  const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3001/0xed5af388653567af2f388e6224dc7c4b3241c544");
  const collection = await res.json();
  return { props: { collection: collection } };
};

Dashboard.getLayout = function getLayout(page: ReactElement) {
  return (
    <CollectionLayout collection={page.props.collection}>
      {page}
    </CollectionLayout>
  );
};

export default Dashboard;
```

Comment: _"I am adding unnecessary strain on the server by making multiple calls for redundant data"_ - Couldn't that be solved by [caching](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-server-side-props#caching-with-server-side-rendering-ssr) the data you fetch in `getServerSideProps`?

Comment: @juliomalves do you know if caching works across different pages? I couldn't find any information about this. I would be requesting the same data on different pages. If so, then yes caching would solve my problem!

Comment: `getServerSideProps` caching will be done per page. But you could just do the caching on each page.

Answer (score -1):

There are different ways to persist state in React, the best would be to use Redux or better still, to pass your data as props from  to  that way every direct Child Component of will have access to the data coming from the Parent component. See this [template](https://github.com/Chukwu3meka/NextJs-starter-template).

Pass 'Component' prop to Layout Component from app.js

app.jsx

```
const App = ({ Component, pageProps, seoDataFromGetServerSideProps }) => (
  <Layout {...{ pageProps, Component, seoDataFromGetServerSideProps }} />
);
```

Layout.jsx

```
const Layout = ({ Component, pageProps, seoDataFromGetServerSideProps }) => (
  <>
    <Head>
      {/* pass your SEO data here from seoDataFromGetServerSideProps */}
      <meta httpEquiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
      <meta httpEquiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charSet=utf-8" />

      <meta name="theme-color" content={seoDataFromGetServerSideProps.theme} />
      <meta name="keywords" content={seoDataFromGetServerSideProps.title} />
      <meta httpEquiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charSet=utf-8" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
      <meta name="description" content={seoDataFromGetServerSideProps.title} />
    </Head>
    <HeaderContainer />
    <Component {...pageProps} seoDataFromGetServerSideProps={seoDataFromGetServerSideProps } />
    <FooterContainer />
  </>
);

export default Layout;
```

```
const HomePage = ({seoDataFromGetServerSideProps }) => (
  // return home page 
)

const AboutPage = ({seoDataFromGetServerSideProps }) => (
  // return about page 
)
```

Both HomePage and AboutPage will have whatever you've passed Layout

I hope you get the Idea.

Comment: This ties `App` to a specific layout (`Layout` here)? The question implies that all pages under `/collection/[contractaddress]` share the same layout (`CollectionLayout`), but that doesn't mean all pages do.

Comment: Your answer also doesn't make it clear where `getServerSideProps` would be defined.

Comment: If its not a root element, you can fetch data from any source and save to Redux, then any Component/Page can access this data from redux store

Comment: Still, this answer is incomplete and it's not a vanilla Next.js solution.